# Big Bang Theory Challenge

Tags: javascript, encryption, translation

In the big bang episode I was watching today (Season 11, Episode 20), Dr. Wolcott, nut job theoretical cosmologist, wrote his notes backward and changed all of the letters to numbers, which made it very difficult for Sheldon to read. I thought this would be a good challenge for me to solve since I am new to programming.

I was able to create a function that can encrypt the words to numbers so Sheldon could communicate with Dr. Wolcott, but I was unable to decrypt the numbers to words for Dr. Wolcott to communicate with Sheldon.

**The main issue I am having is converting double-digit numbers to letters.**

**For example, encrypt('z') would return 25, the index of that letter, but decrypt('25') would return 'fc' not 'z'**

I am having difficulties refactoring and picking good variable names so sorry in advance. Also thank for your help I greatly appreciate it.

```
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const alphabetArray = alphabet.split('');


const encrypt = (sentence) => {
    const sentenceArray = sentence.toLowerCase().split('').reverse();

    const encryption = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < sentenceArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (sentenceArray[i] === ' ') {
            encryption.push(' ');
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < alphabetArray.length; j += 1) {
            if (sentenceArray[i] === alphabetArray[j]) {
                const letterIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(alphabetArray[j]);
                encryption.push(letterIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    return encryption.join('');
};

encrypt('Abc Def');



const decrypt = (numbers) => {
    const numbersArray = numbers.split('').reverse();

    const decryption = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (numbersArray[i] === ' ') {
            decryption.push(' ');
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < alphabetArray.length; j += 1) {
            if (parseInt(numbersArray[i]) === alphabetArray.indexOf(alphabetArray[j])) {
                decryption.push(alphabetArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return decryption.join('');
};

decrypt('543 210');
```

Comment: You should make following changes instead of using value of A as 1 you should use 01, 2 as 02, 3 03 ... And use 0 as 00. By using this form each letter will be in two digit form and you can easily separate.

Comment: You're not giving the program the way to differentiate between decrypting 'fc', or 'z'. In other words, there should be some sort of delimiter to tell the program when to stop interpreting the entry as a letter (e.g. a comma, space, or newline). @SankalpBhamare's suggestion works pretty well.

Comment: If you don't want to use this method you can use a secret deliminator, ASCII symbol U+200C , this symbol is invisible , but is present in string and will allow you to separate each entry in array...  So your string can be like 1|23|0| |20|37 this '|' is an invisible character it will not be visible but when you iterate or copy string it will work.

Comment: This is an interesting question as it hilights the principle of utf-8 encoding: There each ASCII character will be encoded using a single byte (using only the lower 7 bits). Members of extended character sets are encoded in longer byte sequences. These are "announced" by the first byte (e.g. having the highest bit set and specifying how many bytes are to follow). So you need to have a similar algorithm by which you can determine whether you are looking at a single or double digit number.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to my comment above, the following code should work.

```js
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const alphabetArray = alphabet.split('');


const encrypt = (sentence) => {
    const sentenceArray = sentence.toLowerCase().split('').reverse();

    const encryption = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < sentenceArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (sentenceArray[i] === ' ') {
            encryption.push(' ');
        }
        else {
            const letterIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(sentenceArray[i]);
            if (letterIndex < 10)
                encryption.push('0' + letterIndex);
            else
                encryption.push(letterIndex);
        }
    }
    return encryption.join('');
};

e = encrypt('abc Def');
console.log(e);

const decrypt = (numbers) => {
    const decryption = [];
    
    const numSegments = numbers.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < numSegments.length; i += 1) {
        numSegment = numSegments[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < numSegment.length; j += 2){
            alphabetPosition = parseInt(numSegment.substring(j, j+2));
            decryption.push(alphabet[alphabetPosition]);
        }
        if (i < numSegments.length - 1) {
            decryption.push(' ');
        }
    }

    return decryption.reverse().join('');
};

d = decrypt('050403 020100');
console.log(d);
```